# Entity framework in order

Tags: entity

[image]

Sourcefile and file name are the source path  . Archive folder and the archive filename is the destination folder . The value of the input file should be moved to the destination file.Getting error while copying file from source to destination. Showing "File has been already created". Please let me know how to find the directory of a source file without hardcode. How can I write the valid details in another file in the XML Format.

```
    using System; using System.Collections.Generic;using System.IO;
using System.Linq;using System.Security; using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using EmployeeValidation;
using static EmployeeValidation.FundsValidatorException;

namespace FundsValidator
{
    public class empValidator
    {
        public bool ProcessData(string sourceFolder, string fileName, string archiveFolder, string archiveFileName, SqlConnection connection)
        {

            List<Order> Orders = ReadAllDataFromInputFile(sourceFolder,fileName);



            //Step 2
            //SetValidationFlag
            List<Order> ValidOrder = SetValidationFlag(Orders);

            //Step 3
            //InsertOrderData
            bool insertBit = InsertOrderData(ValidOrder, connection);

            //Step 4            
            //GetProductsCommission


            DataTable dtprodcomm = GetProductsCommission(connection);

            //Step 5
            //archive file
            bool archive = CopyToArchive( sourceFileName,  sourceFilePath,  archiveFileName,  archiveFilePath)

            return true;
        }


        public List<Order> ReadAllDataFromInputFile(string sourceFolder, string fileName)
        {
            List<Order> inputlist = null;

            {
                try
                {
                    inputlist = new List<Order>();
                    var inputlines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFolder + fileName);
                    foreach (var item in inputlines)
                    {
                        string[] datas = item.Split(',');
                        Order orderdetails = new Order()
                        {
                            OrderId = datas[0],
                            SalesPersonId = datas[1],
                            OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datas[2]).ToShortDateString(),
                            ModelNbr = datas[3],
                            Quantity = datas[4],
                            CustomerId = datas[5],
                            DeliveryDate = datas[6]
                        };
                        inputlist.Add(orderdetails);
                    }

                }
                catch(OrderProcessorException)
                {
                    throw new OrderProcessorException();
                }
            }


            return inputlist;
        }



        public List<Order> SetValidationFlag(List<Order> Orders)
        {
            List<Order> validList = null;

            validList = new List<Order>();

            int num = 0;

            DateTime dtOrderdate;
            DateTime dtdeliverydate;

            if (Orders != null && Orders.Count >0)
            {
                foreach(var item in Orders)
                {
                    if(int.TryParse(item.OrderId, out num) &&
                        item.SalesPersonId.StartsWith("SP") && item.SalesPersonId.Substring(2).Length == 3 && int.TryParse(item.SalesPersonId.Substring(2), out num) &&
                        DateTime.TryParse(item.OrderDate, out dtOrderdate) &&
                         item.ModelNbr.StartsWith("ML") && item.ModelNbr.Substring(2).Length == 3 && int.TryParse(item.ModelNbr.Substring(2), out num) &&
                        int.TryParse(item.Quantity, out num) && DateTime.TryParse(item.DeliveryDate, out dtdeliverydate) && (Convert.ToDateTime(item.DeliveryDate) - Convert.ToDateTime(item.OrderDate)).TotalDays > 7)
                    {
                        item.ValidFlag = "V";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.ValidFlag = "E";
                    }

                    validList.Add(item);
                }

            }


            return validList;
        }

        public bool InsertOrderData(List<Order> Orders, SqlConnection connectionString)
        {
            bool bret = true;

            {
                if(Orders !=null && Orders.Count >0)
                {
                   foreach(var item in Orders)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand command = connectionString.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            command.CommandText = "Insert into SBA.Orders(OrderId,SalesPersonId,OrderDate,ModelNbr,Quantity,CustomerId,Deliverydate,ValidFlag) Values('" + item.OrderId + "','" + item.SalesPersonId + "','" + item.OrderDate + "','" + item.ModelNbr + "','" + item.Quantity + "','" + item.CustomerId + "','" + item.DeliveryDate + "','" + item.ValidFlag + "')";
                            command.Connection = connectionString;
                            connectionString.Open();
                            int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            connectionString.Close();
                            if (count > 0)
                            {
                                bret = true;
                            }
                            else

                                bret = false;

                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    bret = false;
                }
            }

            return bret;



        }

        public DataTable GetProductsCommission(SqlConnection connectionString)
        {
            DataTable dtProductsCommission = null;

            using (SqlCommand command = connectionString.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "Select ModelNbr,Commission_Percentage,Base_Price from SBA.Product_Commission";
                command.Connection = connectionString;
                connectionString.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dtProductsCommission = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            return dtProductsCommission;

        }
       public bool InsertCommissionData(List<Order> Orders, DataTable dtProductsCommission, SqlConnection connectionString)
        {

            bool bret = true;

            if (Orders != null && Orders.Count > 0 && dtProductsCommission.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in Orders)
                {
                    if (item.ValidFlag == "V")
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtProductsCommission.Rows)
                        {
                            float commamt = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Commission_Percentage"]) * Convert.ToInt32(dr["Base_Price"]) * Convert.ToInt32(item.Quantity);

                            using (SqlCommand cmd = connectionString.CreateCommand())
                            {
                                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into SBA.Order_Commission(OrderId,CommissionAmt) Values('" + item.OrderId + "','" + commamt + "')";
                                connectionString.Open();
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                connectionString.Close();
                                bret = true;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                bret = false;
            }

                    return bret;
        }


        public bool CopyToArchive(string sourceFileName, string sourceFilePath, string archiveFileName, string archiveFilePath)
        {
            bool bret = true;

            if(!File.Exists(archiveFilePath + archiveFileName))
            {
                File.Copy(sourceFilePath + sourceFileName, archiveFilePath + archiveFileName);

            }
            else
            {
                File.Delete(archiveFilePath + archiveFileName);

                File.Copy(sourceFilePath + sourceFileName, archiveFilePath + archiveFileName);
            }

            return bret;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
I have fixed this problem.Please refer this program for more details        

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Data.Sql;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.Xml;

    namespace EmployeeValidation
    {
        public class FundsValidator
        {

            public void ProcessData(string FilePath, string FileName, SqlConnection connection, string errorFilename, string errorFilepath)
            {
                List<Funds> Alllstfunds = new List<Funds>();
                List<Funds> Validlstfunds = new List<Funds>();
                Alllstfunds= ReadValuesfromInputfile(FilePath, FileName);
                Validlstfunds = GetValidFunds(Alllstfunds,  errorFilename,  errorFilepath);
                SaveValidListToDB(Validlstfunds,connection);
                List<Funds> Removeddup= GerPerFundDetails(Validlstfunds);
                CalculateNavandSaveToDatabase(Removeddup,connection);



            }
            public List<Funds> ReadValuesfromInputfile(string FilePath, string FileName)
            {
                List<Funds> AllListfunds = new List<Funds>();
                string s1= null;
                StreamReader sw = File.OpenText(FilePath + FileName);
                while ((s1 = sw.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Funds fund = new Funds();
                    string[] s = s1.Split(',');
                    fund.FundsID = s[0].ToString();
                    fund.SubfundID = s[1].ToString();
                    fund.Asset = s[2].ToString();
                    fund.La = s[3].ToString();
                    fund.o = s[4].ToString();
                    AllListfunds.Add(fund);

                }
                return AllListfunds;
            }

             public List<Funds> GetValidFunds(List<Funds> Alllstfunds, string errorFilename,string  errorFilepath)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     List<Funds> validlist = new List<Funds>();
                     List<Funds> Invalid = new List<Funds>();
                     foreach (Funds x in Alllstfunds)
                     {
                         bool valid = true;
                         valid = valid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FundsID) && x.FundsID.StartsWith("F")) && x.FundsID.Length == 4 && x.FundsID.Substring(1).Length == 3 && x.FundsID.Substring(1).All(char.IsDigit);
                         valid = valid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SubfundID)) && x.SubfundID.StartsWith("SF") && x.SubfundID.Length == 5 && x.SubfundID.Substring(2).Length == 3 && x.SubfundID.Substring(2).All(char.IsDigit);
                         valid = valid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Asset)) && x.Asset.All(char.IsDigit);
                         valid = valid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.La)) && x.La.All(char.IsDigit);
                         valid = valid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.o)) && x.o.All(char.IsDigit);
                         if (valid)
                         {
                             validlist.Add(x);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             Invalid.Add(x);
                         }
                     }
                     SaveInValidinErrorTxt(Invalid, errorFilename, errorFilepath);
                     return validlist;
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     throw new FundsValidatorException(ex.Message);
                 }
             }
            public void SaveInValidinErrorTxt(List<Funds> Invalid,string errorFilename,string errorFilepath)
            {
                if (Invalid.Count > 0 && Invalid != null)
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(errorFilepath + errorFilename))
                    {
                        var i=File.Create(errorFilepath + errorFilename);
                        i.Close();
                    }
                     StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(errorFilepath+errorFilename);
                    foreach (Funds f in Invalid)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(f.FundsID+","+f.SubfundID+","+f.Asset+","+f.La+","+f.o);
                    }
                    sw.Flush();
                    sw.Close();

                }
            }
            public void SaveValidListToDB(List<Funds> Validlstfunds, SqlConnection connection)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (Funds f in Validlstfunds)
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("Insert into SBA.Fund_Details (FundId,SubFundId,Assets,Liabilities,OutstandingShares) Values ( '" + f.FundsID + "','" + f.SubfundID + "','" + f.Asset + "','" + f.La + "','" + f.o + "')"), connection);
                        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new FundsValidatorException(ex.Message);
                }

            }
            public List<Funds> GerPerFundDetails(List<Funds> Validlists)
            {
                List<string> s = new List<string>();
                List<Funds> RemoveDup = new List<Funds>();
                String[] r = (from a in Validlists
                         select a.FundsID).Distinct().ToArray();
                foreach (String x in r)
                {
                    int assetnum = 0;
                    int lanum = 0;
                    int onum=0;
                    foreach (Funds q in Validlists)
                    {
                        if (x.ToString() == q.FundsID)
                        {
                            assetnum = assetnum + int.Parse(q.Asset);
                            lanum=lanum+int.Parse(q.La);
                            onum=onum+int.Parse(q.o);
                        }
                    }
                    Funds f= new Funds();
                    f.FundsID=x.ToString();
                    f.Asset=assetnum.ToString();
                    f.La=lanum.ToString();
                    f.o= onum.ToString();
                    RemoveDup.Add(f);

                }
                return RemoveDup;
            }
            public void CalculateNavandSaveToDatabase(List<Funds> Removeddup,SqlConnection connection)
            {
                List<Funds> NAVClaculated = new List<Funds>();
                foreach(Funds item in Removeddup)
                {
                     item.NAV= (float)(Math.Round(((float.Parse(item.Asset) - float.Parse(item.La))/(float.Parse(item.o))),2));

                    NAVClaculated.Add(item);
                }
                foreach (Funds f in NAVClaculated)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("Insert into SBA.Nav_Report (FundId,Assets,Liabilities,OutstandingShares,Nav) Values ( '" + f.FundsID + "','" + f.Asset + "','" + f.La + "','" + f.o +"','"+f.NAV+ "')"), connection);
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    namespace Tarriffs
{
    public class Tariff
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string LastMeterReading { get; set; }
        public string CurrentMeterReading { get; set; }
        public string ReadingDate { get; set; }
        public string NoofUnits { get; set; }
        public string CalculatedAmount { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputfile = @"D:\Tarriffs\Input file\Tarriff_0919.txt";
            List<Tariff> read = new List<Tariff>();
            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(inputfile);
            string s= null;
            while((s= sr.ReadLine())!=null)
            {
                string[] item = s.Split(',');
                Tariff tar = new Tariff();
                tar.UserId= item[0];
                tar.UserName= item[1];
                tar.Category= item[2];
                tar.LastMeterReading= item[3];
                tar.CurrentMeterReading= item[4];
                tar.ReadingDate= item[5];
                bool valid = validandlogger(tar.UserId, tar.UserName, tar.Category, tar.LastMeterReading, tar.CurrentMeterReading, tar.ReadingDate);
                if (valid)
                {
                    double[] tarriffcalculation = tarriffcalc(tar.LastMeterReading, tar.CurrentMeterReading);
                    Tariff final = new Tariff();
                    final.UserId = item[0];
                    final.UserName = item[1];
                    final.NoofUnits = tarriffcalculation[0].ToString();
                    final.CalculatedAmount = tarriffcalculation[1].ToString();
                    SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NA03OSDVP00746\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBTarriffValidation;Integrated Security=True");
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into dbo.custom values ('" + final.UserId + "','" + final.UserName + "','" + final.NoofUnits + "','" + final.CalculatedAmount + "')", conn);

                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        public static bool validandlogger(string UserId, string UserName, string Category, string LastMeterReading, string CurrentMeterReading, string ReadingDate)
        {
            bool valid = true;
            DateTime dt;
            Regex name = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}$");
            valid = valid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId)) && UserId.All(char.IsDigit);
            valid = valid && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName)) && name.IsMatch(UserName);
            string[] vcategory = { "COM", "DOM", "OTD" };
            valid = valid && vcategory.Contains(Category);
            valid = valid && LastMeterReading.All(char.IsDigit);
            valid = valid && CurrentMeterReading.All(char.IsDigit);
            valid = valid && DateTime.TryParseExact(ReadingDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
            if (!valid)
            {

                string errortextfile = @"D:\Tarriffs\Error_log\";
                string errorfile = "Error_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("MMyyyy")+".txt";
                if (!File.Exists(errortextfile + errorfile))
                {
                    var i = File.Create(errortextfile + errorfile);
                    i.Close();
                }
                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(errortextfile + errorfile);
                sw.WriteLine(UserId + "," + UserName + "," + Category + "," + LastMeterReading + "," + CurrentMeterReading + "," + ReadingDate);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
        public static double[] tarriffcalc(string LastMeterReading, string CurrentMeterReading)
        {
            int LMeterReading = 0;
            int CMeterReading = 0;
            LMeterReading = int.Parse(LastMeterReading);
            CMeterReading = int.Parse(CurrentMeterReading);
            int units = CMeterReading - LMeterReading;
            double totalamount = 0;
            if (units <= 100)
            {
                var baserate = 20;
                totalamount = (units * 1) + baserate;
            }
            else if (units <= 200)
            {
                var baserate = 20;
                totalamount = (units * 1.5) + baserate;
            }
            else if (units <= 500)
            {
                var baserate = 40;
                totalamount = 250 +((units-200)*3)+baserate;
            }
            else if (units > 500)
            {
                var baserate = 40;
                totalamount = 1700 + ((units - 500) * 5.75) + baserate;
            }
            return new double[] {units,totalamount};
        }
    }
}
```